# Cannot delete files from Samba share

Tags: xbian, samba, share

I am running XBian Beta 2. I have a external hdd connected using usb with this fstab entry

```
/dev/sda1       /media/mybook   ext3    defaults,noauto,user,exec,noatime       0       0       0
```

I want this disk to be available through samba. I added this to `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

```
[mybook]
    path = /media/mybook
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
    force user = xbian
    browseable = yes
```

Those parameters are exactly the same as parameters for my home folder. The problem is that although I can delete files from the home folder, I cannot delete files from `[mybook]` using samba.

When I try do delete a file, I get

```
You require permissions from XBIAN\xbian to make changes to this file
```

All the files I want to delete using samba have owner set to `xbian` and permissions to `777`.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In my options I don't have the

```
read only = no
```

option, but a

```
writable = yes
```

option.

Did you try this already?

**Update:**
I tried the same as you: sharing a external HDD. The problem was, that the HDD was not mounted propperly. So only root could do anything on this directory. There were two methodes which worked for me.

1.

```
force user = root
```

2.

```
mount -o umask=007,gid=1000,uid=1003 /dev/sda1 /media/mybook
```

Here uid is the user-ID and gid is the group-ID. The correct IDs you can find out by

```
less /etc/passwd
```

But maybe you should first check your permissions

```
ls -la /media
```

to enshure, if it is the problem or not.

Comment: yes I did, no help

Answer (score -3):

try adding something like into your smb.conf:

```
force create mode = 0777
force directory mode = 0777
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
```

Comment: Did not help and I guess it is only for creating files and directories, which I also cannot do

Comment: This also is a security mistake. World readable/writable files and Directories are seldom a good idea.